# Importing dates to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

I cannot seem to find any info on this..

I need to convert a string to a date so that it will import properly to an SQL DATE field. When I import `12/25/2012` to the DB, it appears as `0000-00-00`.

What's the proper way to do this?

Links and refs appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428957/722783) pointed out in his answer, MySQL accepts dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Quoted from [***11.1.5. Date and Time Types***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date
>   parts must always be given in year-month-day order

For this, you can use [**`str_todate()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)<sup>2</sup> function to format it:

```
str_to_date('12/25/2012', '%m/%d/%Y);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dee65/5)

This way, these input strings will be stored in your database as date objects(without any specific date format). Later, if you want to output these dates in a specific format you can use [**`DATE_FORMAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)<sup>3</sup> to format it. Something like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM Test;
--2012-12-25
```

<sup>**1, 2, 3:** <sup>Links and refs, that you asked for.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

MySQL accepts dates in this format `YYYY-MM-DD` either change your date format `12/25/2012` to `2012-12-25` or modify them to match the correct format.

**EDIT**
If you want to continue using your own format try this

```
list($d,$m,$y) = explode("/", "12/25/2012"); //replace 12/25/2012 with your date
$hyphenDate = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;
echo  $hyphenDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class DateTime. Examples:

```
$SomeDate = new DateTime();
echo $SomeDate->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );  //Must be MySQL compatible (YYYY-MM-DD)

$ThisDate = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
echo $ThisDate->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );  //Must be MySQL compatible (YYYY-MM-DD)
```